# Change column width of itemize nested in enumerate in paracol

Tags: enumerate, itemize, paracol, column-width

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}

    \switchcolumn[1]* \section*{Heading in Language 1}
    \switchcolumn[0]  \section*{Heading in Language 2}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \switchcolumn[1]* \item Text in language 1
        \switchcolumn[0]  \item Text in language 2
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \switchcolumn[1]* Why does this spill over? Shouldn't it wrap?
                \item \switchcolumn[0]  Why does this spill over? It shouldn't go into margins.
            \end{itemize}
        \switchcolumn[1]* \item More text in language 1
        \switchcolumn[0]  \item More text in language 2
        \switchcolumn[1]* \item Yet more text in language 1
        \switchcolumn[0]  \item Yet more text in language 2
    \end{enumerate}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

## Output:

[image]

How do I change the column width of the itemize environment and prevent it from spilling over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Again, your MWE violates the rule "don't do \switchcolumn in a list-like environments (enumerate, itemize, etc.) included in paracol."  The following obeys the rule and thus works well.

```
    \begin{enumerate}
      \begin{paracol}{2}
        \switchcolumn[1]* \item ...
        \switchcolumn[0]  \item ...
        \switchcolumn[1]*
          \begin{itemize} \item ...
          \end{itemize}
        \switchcolumn[0]
          \begin{itemize} \item ...
          \end{itemize}
        \switchcolumn[1]* \item ...
        \switchcolumn[0]  \item ...
        \switchcolumn[1]* \item ...
        \switchcolumn[0]  \item ...
     \end{paracol}
    \end{enumerate}
```

If you have two or more \item-s to be aligned in the itemize environment, you need to do some dirty trick to have proper inter-\item spaces.  For example, with the following \def-initions in your preamble;

```
    \makeatlatter
    \def\FirstList{\@topsepadd\z@}
    \def\MidList{\@newlistfalse \@topsepadd\z@}
    \def\LastList{\@newlistfalse}
    \makeatother
```

you'll have proper spaces by adding one of them to \begin{itemize} as follows.

```
    \begin{itemize}\Firstlist % for the first chunk
    \begin{itemize}\MidList   % for non-first/non-last chunks
    \begin{itemize}\LastList  % for the last chunk
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\usepackage{enumitem}` and add something like `[rightmargin=\leftmargin]` at the end of `\begin{itemize}`.

## Result:

[image]

Comment: Trying this with `enumerate` instead of `itemize` (but also with `itemize`), the text of the left column still spills into the numbering (or bullet points) of the right column.

Comment: One more note, by using `\selectlanguage` and having `babel` primed to the language I use, I can also minimize the spillover, because now hyphenation works properly.