# paracol description list wrap title

Tags: lists, description, paracol

I am writing a bilingual glossary using paracol, but I have two questions about it.  First, when using the "description" list, items with a long name do not wrap onto lines.  Second, when I have two section headings at the start of the description list, the vertical alignment of the first list items is off.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\switchcolumn[0]*
\section{Language 1 Column}

\switchcolumn[1]
\section{Language 2 Column}


\begin{description}

\switchcolumn[0]*
\item [{Item 1:}] The first description for item 1, in language 1.

\switchcolumn[1]
\item [{Item 1:}] The first description for item 1, in language 2.

\switchcolumn[0]* 
\item [{Item 2 has a really long name which doesn't wrap lines:}]  The second description, for the item with a really long name, in language 1.

\switchcolumn[1]
\item [{Item 2 has a really long name which doesn't wrap lines:}]  The second description, for the item with a really long name, in language 2.

\end{description}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the description title wrapping, you can use the `unboxed` style.
 For the alignment problem, close the description environment after the first item, and reopen it afterwards, as in this code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\columnsep}{50pt}

\begin{paracol}{2}

\switchcolumn[0]*
\section{Language 1 Column}

\switchcolumn[1]
\section{Language 2 Column}

\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
\switchcolumn[0]*
\item [{Item 1:}] The first description for item 1, in language 1.
\end{description}

\switchcolumn[1]
\begin{description}[style=unboxed]
\item [{Item 1:}] The first description for item 1, in language 2.

\switchcolumn[0]*
\item [{Item 2 has a really long name which wraps lines:}] The second description, for the item with a really long name, in language 1.

\switchcolumn[1]
\item [{Item 2 has a really long name which wraps lines:}] The second description, for the item with a really long name, in language 2.

\end{description}

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The use of "[style=unboxed]" fixed the wrapping issue - thank you!  However, the suggestion of closing the description environment after the first item, and reopening it afterwards, to fix the alignment issue does not work 100%.  If you do that, the vertical blank space between the first and second items is larger than between subsequent items.  The solution I found was to put the paracol environment inside the description environment, instead of the other way around.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484438/change-column-width-of-itemize-nested-in-enumerate-in-paracol/484758.

Comment: That seems to be a good solution? For the spacing problem with my solution, one may use, for the second description environment: `\begin{description}[style=unboxed, topsep=\itemsep]`.